# Android Firefox-debug per USB, Inspector shows nothing

Tags: android, debugging, firefox, web-inspector

I try to inspect a webpage on Firefox-Nightly on Windows 10 PC, but the inspector shows nothing. No Screen, no html, nor CSS.
The Connection was successfull.
I can use the console, the debugger, DOM inspector, Network everything,

[image]

[image]

only the inspector doesn't work.

[image]
Clicking in the DOM-pannel or the debugger on the symbol, to inspect an html-element, the view changed to the empty inspector.

Answer (score 0):

Just had that same issue, the solution for me was to **update both mobile and desktop browsers** that were not the same version